# Количество потоков OMP

Tags: c++, распараллеливание

Как рассчитать количество потоков, которые можно выделить для выполнения задач параллельного программирования на OMP

Comment: Без знания условия задачи — никак.

Comment: Я имею ввиду, сколько потоков физически может выделить компьютер

Comment: Если процессор двухъядерный — 4 потока, если восьмиядерный – 16 потоков.

Comment: Вот ссылка на вопрос [Максимальное колличество одновременных потоков](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/872005/Максимальное-колличество-одновременных-потоков)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Максимальное количество одновременных потоков](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/872005/%d0%9c%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2)

Comment: Этого не требуется. Потоки выделяются рантаймом openmp.

Comment: Ваша реализация OMP будет использовать количество потоков, которое возвращает функция `omp_get_num_threads()`, а она возвращает одно из следующих значений: результат внутреннего алгоритма анализа вашей аппаратуры, либо значение переменной окружения `OMP_NUM_THREADS`, либо значение ранее заданное функцией `omp_set_num_threads()`.